# Trying to self delete a file with unlink() with no success

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

A new client who has a WordPress site needed to access his administration from which he was locked out by the person who setup the site. He only had FTP access so I had to create a script to connect to the DB and run a password change query. (yes I did confirm that he was truly the owner).

Because the file must be deleted after use, I placed `unlink(__FILE__);` at the end of the process, **but the file remained**.

#### The code (hopefully not considered unethical)

```
<?php

if( file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-config.php') ) 
{
    include 'wp-config.php';
    
    $dbconnect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    $usertbl = $table_prefix.'users';
    $usermeta = $table_prefix.'usermeta';
    $userlvl = $table_prefix.'user_level';
    
    $users = "
    SELECT ID, user_login, user_email 
    FROM $usertbl 
    LEFT JOIN $usermeta 
    ON $usertbl.ID = $usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE meta_key = '$userlvl'
    AND meta_value = 10
    ";

    $res = $dbconnect->query($users);
    $usr= $optname='';
    if( $res->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $usr .= '<ul><li>'.$row['user_login'].'</li><li>'.$row['user_email'].'</li></ul>';
            $optname .= '<option value="'.$row['user_login'].'">'.$row['user_login'].'</option>';
        }
    }

    if( $dbconnect->connect_error ) {
        echo '<p style="color:red">DB connection failed: ('.$dbconnect->connect_errno.') '.$dbconnect->connect_error.'<br>Database connection was blocked</p>';
        exit();
    }
    
    // Run password update  
    $result='';
    if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pwset']) ) 
    {
        $password = '"'.MD5($_POST['pwset']).'"';
        $username = '"'.$_POST['username'].'"';
        $query = "UPDATE $usertbl SET user_pass = $password WHERE user_login = $username";
        $admin = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']).'/wp-admin';
        
        if( $dbconnect->query($query) === TRUE ) 
        {
            $result = '<p class="success">The password update ran successfully.</p>';
            $result .= '<p class="success">Now redirecting to admin...</p>';
            
            // redirect to admin login in 7 seconds
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7; URL='.$admin.'" />';

            // file self delete
            unlink(__FILE__);
        }
    }


} ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reset</title>
<style>
body {font-family: verdana; font-size: 13px; padding: 0 50px 50px;}
a {text-decoration: none; color: #b22525; font-weight: 900;}
input, select {display: block; border: 1px solid #bbb; padding: 4px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
.notice {background: #ddf7ff; padding: 8px;}
.notice-alert {background: #ffdde1; padding: 8px; font-size: 28px; text-align: center; color: #ce0100; font-weight: 900;}
.success {background: #f1ffdb; padding: 8px;}
input[type="submit"] {cursor: pointer;}
input[type="text"] {font-family: courier; padding: 3px;}
.footnote {text-align: center; background: #f2f2f2; padding: 5px;}
.list {margin: 20px 0;}
.list ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.list li {float: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #eee; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box;}
.list .th {background: #ddd; font-weight: 900;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<?php if( !file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-config.php') ) {
    echo '
    <p class="notice-alert">
    This file must be in the WordPress root directory where the wp-config.php file is located.
    </p>
    ';
}else{
    if( !empty($dbconnect->stat) ) 
        echo '<p class="notice">database connection OK</p>';
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <h3>Admin Password Reset</h3>
    <p class="notice-alert">Be sure to delete this file once done</p>

    Select the user name to update*<br />
    <select name="username" required="required">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <?php echo $optname; ?>
    </select>
    Set new password*<br />
    <input type="text" name="pwset" value="" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" name="pwsend" value="Reset Password" />
<?php echo $result; ?>
</form>


<div class="list">
    <h4>List of Administrators Found In User Database</h4>
    <ul class="th"><li>Username</li><li>Email</li></ul>
    <?php echo $usr; ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

#### The output

[image: image of form output]

**What's missing in the process to get the self delete to run?**

Comment: have you looked at the log? what steps have you tried to debug?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond there's no error thrown. The process runs as expected to update the DB row, then redirect to the admin URL, but the file is not deleting itself as I thought it would. I can't think of any logs to check.

Comment: it could be the permission of web user that it has permission to read but not permission to delete file.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond the permission appears to be the case. I ran the script on a different server and it self deleted as expected. Thanks for the tip.